# Iphone: NSInvocation changes references of arguments?

Tags: iphone, reference, memory-address

I'm trying to set up an NSinvocation to upload a picture to a website.  I'm doing this:

1. Set up the nsinvocation object
2. Add a UIImage* to the nsinvocation object as an argument, along with some other arguments
3. invoke the nsinvocation when needed
4. the function called when I invoke nsinvocation can't access the UIImage- I get NSInvalidArgumentException.

After digging for a little while, It looks like if I add a UIImage as an argument to my NSInvocation object, then try to get it back out... I am returned a different memory address!  Is this normal?

//*First I have a valid UIImage "imgHolder" which has a memory address of "A"...*

**NSInvocation *myInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:...**

**[myInvocation setArgument:imgHolder atIndex:5];**

//*Now, the weird part...*

**UIImage *checkImg;**

**[myInvocation getArgument:&checkImg atIndex:12];**

//*checkImg has a memory address of "B"!*

if I try to work with checkImg, I get various exceptions which leads me to believe it's not a valid UIImage.

Any ideas what's going on?  Shouldn't the memory address of checkImg be identical to that of  imgHolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[myInvocation setArgument:imgHolder atIndex:5];`

If imgHolder is a UIImage*, you should pass &imgHolder, not imgHolder.

Comment: Oops. =)  Thanks.

(If they didn't make the 7 button so hard to reach when holding shift, this probably wouldn't happen so often...)